# OpenBSD AnonCVS find out which "tree" I am using

Tags: openbsd

I know the FAQ suggests to prefer
the pkg_tools over using the ports tree if you are not so experienced with the package system.

But anyhow, I just wanted to know if there is a way to find out which source tree I have cloned
over AnonCVS, because its been a while since I have installed my ports tree and I read that 
it is important to know before you upgrade them sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the `/usr/src/CVS/Tag` file, should contain the branch name originally used at checkout *(ex, `TOPENBSD_5_4` for 5.4-stable)* if not from `-current` 
Its very important not to cross `-current` and `-source/-release` trees - Did you ever build/install your ports? Have you built a new kernel from source, or compiled any patches? If not, you are likely still running `-release`, in which case to be safe delete the old sources and checkout a fresh `-stable` *(`release` plus security patches)* base and ports, build & install the new kernel, reboot, *then* build the ports. Their process must be followed exactly.
If you think you've compiled and installed any `-current`, then you cannot downgrade to `release/stable`, you'll need to continue with that tree or reinstall.

1. http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#NoFun
2. http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#BldGetSrc
3. http://www.openbsd.org/stable.html